# Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable in binary search tree insert function

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, binary-search-tree

I am getting an error about the pointer variable trail current being potentially uninitialized and I am a little confused on why it is happening.

Here is the insert function that I am having an issue with (the error points me to the last if statement)

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::addCustomer(const elemType& insertItem)
{
    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *current;  //pointer to traverse the tree
    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *newNode;  //pointer to create the node

    newNode = new binaryTreeNode<elemType>;
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->llink = NULL;
    newNode->rlink = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        current = root;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;

            if (current->info == insertItem)
            {
                cerr << "The insert item is already in the list-";
                cerr << "duplicates are not allowed."
                    << insertItem << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->llink;
            else
                current = current->rlink;
        }//end while

        if (trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
            trailCurrent->llink = newNode;
        else
            trailCurrent->rlink = newNode;
    }
}//end insert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just the compiler getting confused. Obviously if `root` is NULL it doesn't go through the else part with while loop at all, and if `root` is not NULL, then `trailCurrent` will always be set to something as it must go through the loop at least once.

If it was me, I would just initialize `trailCurrent` to `root` (or NULL), once I was sure the warning was not correct.